# Conditional AND using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I have the following query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByParams", query=
    "SELECT * 
     FROM User user 
     WHERE user.name type = :inputType")
```

And I wish to add `AND` statement, that will take place only if the inputs are supplied:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByParams", query=
    "SELECT * 
     FROM User user 
     WHERE user.name type = :inputType AND (:ageInput != null AND user.age > :ageInput")
```

It means that if the ageInput is supplied, filter by it as well. If not- ignore this param. Any ideas?

Any ideas?

Comment: not in a named query (as far as i know). use `Criteria` API for this

Comment: Not possible on SQL way! As @XtremeBaumer said, as from JPA2 you can use Criteria API for that

Comment: `... AND (:ageInput == null OR user.age > :ageInput )`

Answer (score 1):

As the previous speakers wrote, you can use Criteria

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria()
        .add(Restrictions.eq("type", type));

if (ageInput != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ageInput", ageInput));
}

List<User> list = criteria.list();
```

or SQLQuery

```
String sql = "SELECT * " +
       "FROM User user " +
       "WHERE user.type = :inputType ";

sql += (ageInput != null) ? "AND ageInput = :ageInput " : "";

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql)
        .setParameter("inputType", inputType);

if(ageInput != null) {
    query.setParameter("ageInput", ageInput);
}

return (List<User>) query.list();
```

Comment: Consider sql injection carefully .. I would build this using the category framework / hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if `ageInput` is supplied or not in code and will have to call different methods accordingly.
Means if `ageInput` is supplied then you will have to call a method having `ageInput` constraint o/w call method which do not have `ageInput` constraint.

Alternatively,  you can use predicates and execute a query.